# Humidity spot in neighbour (below) flat from an empty appartement during confinement?

Tags: leak

My neighbour (below) is complaining of water infiltrating his ceiling and state it's from my flat's shower but :

1. The shower is about 3-4 meters away from this leakage ( more like an
   humidity spot as it's not pouring)
2. The flat wasn't in use since beginning of lockdown (16th of May here,
   in Paris)
3. The plumber didn't find any reason for this besides the shower curtain being a bit short ...

Any idea as to what I should look for ?

Comment: That’s Paris France, not Paris Texas, right? No rain in Texas..how about France?

Comment: The water you see from a leak, could come from the other side of your house (flat).

Comment: A leak can follow along a joist, pipe or wire a fair distance, which makes it hard to find the origin. Check under each sink and tub, and also air-conditioner. The water could even be from a leak in the roof!  @LeeSam, could be Paris, Maine or Pennsylvania... https://www.spudart.org/blog/what-if-all-23-cities-america-named-paris-had-own-eiffel-tow/

Comment: When is the last time you’ve been to your flat?

Comment: @LeeSam Sorry it's Paris, France ! not Texas, Pen or others I don't know about (Only knew of Paris, Texas because of the movie feature)

Comment: @Gunner and harper Yes that the main issue I have : how to make sure the leak described ins't coming from the attached building or from an upper-level flat ?